# pandas - Merge two dataframes on a column and result has more rows than specified how?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two `dataframes`:

```
len(fut_df)
# Result 31505
len(under_df)
# Result 5187659

# Trying to merge them and get all relevant values into a dataframe.
len(pd.merge(fut_df, under_df, on='timestamp', how='left')
# Result 38508 i.e. more than the keys on left dataframe.
```

I have tried `outer`, `inner`. Every time the result dataframe has a length higher than the `fut_df`. I want to merge the `dataframes` and get the values where timestamp matches in both. I am unable to understand why the length I am getting back is higher than the `fut_df`.

Comment: Check for duplicates in ``fut_df``, what your getting might be Cartesian product.

Comment: @sushanth Thanks. I did a `drop_duplicates(subset=['timestamp','contractname')` on both the dataframes.

Comment: Like others said, there are duplicates in the key column `timestamp`. You would help yourself to read on the basics of joins and how they work.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicates in `under_df`.Use [drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and it should work fine, however you need to decide which values to keep.

```
len(pd.merge(fut_df, under_df.drop_duplicates(), on='timestamp', how='left'))
```

In order to check this issue, the parameter `validate` in [pd.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) throws an error if there are duplicated IDs matched in the right DataFrame.

> “many_to_one” or “m:1”: check if merge keys are unique in right dataset.

```
pd.merge(fut_df, under_df.drop_duplicates(), on='timestamp', how='left', validate = 'm:1')
```